# How to get a DialogPreference to popup so that I can create a wizard-style UI?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a number of preferences that need to be set and I want to guide the user through the flow by popping up the individual preference dialogs (ListPreference, EditTextPreference etc.), one at a time so that I can **create a wizard-style UI**.

As the user fills in a pref, it closes and the next one opens up.

As far as I know, the user has to click on a preference for the dialog to popup.

Is there any way to do this **programmatically**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onItemClick` to perform a click on the `preference` item.

Get the preference position from the preference order.

```
int position = findPreference("language").getOrder();
```

`language` is the preference key.

Then, do `onItemClick` on the `preference` item with the position.

```
getPreferenceScreen().onItemClick(null,null,position,0);
```

Comment: onItemClick() is a listener? The docs are unclear on how to use it. anyway, how would I popup the first preference? `http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceScreen.html#onItemClick(android.widget.AdapterView, android.view.View, int, long)`

Comment: Do this getPreferenceScreen().onItemClick(null,null,0,0);

Comment: onItemClick is not a Listener, You can explicitly call this to perform a click on any item

Comment: That worked! any insight on this from you will be much appreciated... **Issues trying to create a custom dialog preference that gets a time period** http://stackoverflow.com/q/23254405/398348